# The bytecode generated by Cpython vs the bytecode generated by Jython

Tags: python, jython, cpython

I read about different implementations of python like cpython, jython and so on.
And I was wondering if the bytecode generated by the compiler Cpython is the same bytecode generated by the compiler Jython?

Comment: No, definitely not.  Jython runs in a Java environment, and therefore must use Java bytecode.  Cpython has its own bytecode, designed specifically for Python.